# Http request to Django hosted on LAN timed out

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, web-hosting

I want to host my Django rest-api on my local server so visitors to my hosted website can make calls to it. It works perfectly on localhost:8000.

What I did was:

I changed ALLOWED_HOSTS in my settings.py file to all ['*']

```
python3 manage.py runserver 0:8000
```

But now when I try to make a call to or visit http://IP:8000/ I get:

```
(quizkly_env) DN0a22641a:web shiningsunnyday$ http --json POST http://IP:8000/quizkly/ content="Barack Obama was the 44th president of the United States."

http: error: Request timed out (30s).
(quizkly_env) DN0a22641a:web shiningsunnyday$
```

I also tried

```
python3 manage.py runserver IP:8080
```

but got:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced). 
January 25, 2019 - 03:28:56 Django version 2.1.5, using settings 'quizkly.settings' 
Starting development server at http://IP:8080/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Error: That IP address can't be assigned to.
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: the development server works only on localhost by default, to open it for external access over your network, you should call it like `runserver 0.0.0.0:8080`. If your PC is not behind a router of ports are being forwarded, then you should be able to connect across the internet.

Comment: @PabloAlbornoz I did that and it works. What address do I call it over the internet? I tried to access 0.0.0.0:8080 with say, my phone, but it doesn't work...

Comment: You should use the IP your service provider assigned you. Remember, this only works if you're connected directly to the Internet, otherwise, you should set up your router port-forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run it in your network

```
python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

And on the server your connecting to it with, use the IP

Comment: How do I run it on the server with my IP? Sorry this is the first time I'm doing this...

Comment: Say server A is the server running it, on server B you'd just connect to it with A's IP, eg: Server A's IP is 192.168.5.1, you'd use `192.168.5.1:8000`

Comment: How do I account for the IP changing? It was working just now but then the IP changed and now it's down again.

Comment: If you're able to set the IP to static do that, otherwise you'll have to constantly change the IP when it changes